# Why can't I iterate through the full array in Metal

Tags: swift, gpu, metal

I have the following code, which I *think* allocates 2 arrays of 16kb of memory, fills one with 7 and the other with 4.

I then run the code and find that only the first 511 items get added together. I'm 80% certain it's to do with the size of the thread groups/thread counts. Any Ideas?

```
func test()
{
    var (device, commandQueue, defaultLibrary, commandBuffer, computeCommandEncoder) = initMetal()

    let alignment:Int = 0x4000
    var xpointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = nil
    var ypointer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = nil

    let numberOfFloats = 4096 //56
    let numberOfBytes: Int = 16384

    let retx = posix_memalign(&xpointer, alignment, numberOfBytes)
    if retx != noErr {
        let err = String(validatingUTF8: strerror(retx)) ?? "unknown error"
        fatalError("Unable to allocate aligned memory: \(err).")
    }

    let rety = posix_memalign(&ypointer, alignment, numberOfBytes)
    if rety != noErr {
        let err = String(validatingUTF8: strerror(rety)) ?? "unknown error"
        fatalError("Unable to allocate aligned memory: \(err).")
    }


    let datax = xpointer!.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: numberOfFloats)
    for index in 0..<numberOfFloats {
        datax[index] = 7.0
    }

    let datay = ypointer!.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: numberOfFloats)
    for index in 0..<numberOfFloats {
        datay[index] = 4.0
    }

    kernelFunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "sigmoid")
    do
    {
        pipelineState = try device.makeComputePipelineState(function: kernelFunction!)
    }
    catch
    {
        fatalError("Unable to create pipeline state")
    }


    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)


    var xvectorBufferNoCopy = device.makeBuffer(bytesNoCopy: xpointer!, length: numberOfBytes, options: [], deallocator: nil)
    computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(xvectorBufferNoCopy, offset: 0, at: 0)

    var yvectorBufferNoCopy = device.makeBuffer(bytesNoCopy: ypointer!, length: numberOfBytes, options: [], deallocator: nil)
    computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(yvectorBufferNoCopy, offset: 0, at: 1)


    var threadgroupCounts = MTLSize(width:32,height:1,depth:1)
    var threadgroups = MTLSize(width:1024, height:1, depth:1)

    computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadgroupCounts)

    computeCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.commit()
    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s")


    let data = ypointer!.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: numberOfFloats)
    for index in 0..<numberOfFloats {
        print("\(index) - \(data[index])")
    }

}

kernel void addTest(const device float *inVector [[ buffer(0) ]],
                device float *outVector [[ buffer(1) ]],
                uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
    outVector[id] = inVector[id] + outVector[id];
}
```

Comment: I had bookmarked your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495730/how-to-align-memory-in-swift-3 which is now deleted. Did you find out why allocating aligned memory with `UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate()` does not work?

Comment: Is `length = 16384` the buffer size or the number of floating point numbers? Your usage of `length` vs `length * MemoryLayout<Float>.size` seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: oh gosh, sorry Martin R - The code above works for memory alignment ONLY if length is 16384. I couldn't get it to work either way.

Comment: @MartinR If I change length to 56...ie the number of values I wanted the Metal part crashes. This side project is sucking my life

Comment: @MartinR - I'll update the code to make it more clear

Comment: I also don't understand why I cant set var threadgroupCounts = MTLSize(width:8,height:8,depth:1), I get: failed assertion `component 1: 8 must be <= 1 for id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]'

Comment: I get the expected result on AMD M370X. Can you describe your configuration?

Comment: As for that last error, your `thread_position_in_grid` is a `uint`, meaning your threadgroup size has to be 1-dimensional.

Comment: Hi @warrenm, This is probably where I'm being not-too-smart: Intel Iris 1536 MB - All I wanted to do was add things up in groups to see what would happen :-/

Comment: Also works for me on an Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB. Which version of OS X/macOS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123805/discussion-between-chris-and-warrenm).